# Programmatically set Cluster, Pool and Jobs Access Control

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Azure Databricks issue.

Is there any way to programmatically set this parameter in Admin Console: Cluster, Pool and Jobs Access Control. I think this is a spark_conf property, but I can't find any informations.

Other question: When a parameter is set, is it possible to export a json parameter file showing all these settings?

Thank you

Comment: look to the https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks & especially https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/pull/415

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the permissions API lets you manage permissions in the Azure Databricks.

> Note: This feature is in public preview

The Permissions API supports several objects and endpoints:

- Token permissions — Manage which users can create or use tokens.
- Password permissions — Manage which users can use password login when
  SSO is enabled.
- Cluster permissions — Manage which users can manage, restart, or
  attach to clusters.
- Pool permissions — Manage which users can manage or attach to pools.
  Some APIs and documentation refer to pools as instance pools.
- Job permissions — Manage which users can view, manage, trigger,
  cancel, or own a job.
- Notebook permissions — Manage which users can read, run, edit or
  manage a notebook.
- Directory permissions — Manage which users can read, run, edit, or
  manage all notebooks in a directory.
- MLflow registered model permissions — Manage which users can read,
  edit, or manage MLflow registered models.

The permissions API is not completely documented on the Azure Databricks REST API page. I would request you to follow the document on [databricks to create Permissions API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/permissions.html).